# How to LOAD XML in MySQL with self-closing tags?

Tags: mysql, xml

I'm trying to load some XML to a MySQL database, but I encountered a problem with self-closing tags. A sample SQL to demonstrate my problem:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `person` (
    `name` VARCHAR(75)
);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `individual` LIKE `person`;

LOAD XML INFILE 'document.xml'
    INTO TABLE `individual`
    ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<individual>';

LOAD XML INFILE 'document.xml'
    INTO TABLE `person`
    ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<person>';
```

When self-closing tags are followed by an element with a start and end tag, the load works as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
    <individual name="John Smith"></individual>
    <person name="Joe Doe" />
    <person name="Jane Doe" />
</document>


SELECT * FROM `individual`;
+------------+
| name       |
+------------+
| John Smith |
+------------+
1 row in set
SELECT * FROM `person`;
+----------+
| name     |
+----------+
| Joe Doe  |
| Jane Doe |
+----------+
2 rows in set
```

But after one element represented with self-closing tags, the following ones are not loaded:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
  <individual name="John Smith" />
  <person name="Joe Doe" />
  <person name="Jane Doe" />
</document>


SELECT * FROM `individual`;
+------------+
| name       |
+------------+
| John Smith |
+------------+
1 row in set
SELECT * FROM `person`;
Empty set
```

How do I load an XML file with multiple self-closing tags into MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bug, you may report it to [MySQL Bugs](http://bugs.mysql.com/).

As a possible workaround, you can generate a XML like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
  <table>
    <individual name="John Smith" />
  </table>
  <table>
    <person name="Joe Doe" />
    <person name="Jane Doe" />
  </table>
</document>
```